# Selenium Automation for Firefox

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am new to selenium automation. I have installed Selenium IDE and selenium RC ( java -jar selenium.jar) as administrator in the system. Also I am using Eclipse SDK version 3.7.1. Getting below error on compiling code (Run As -> TestNG Test)

```
package com.test.webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Driver

{

@Test //This is TestNG annotation

public void testRegister()

{

  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

  driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");

  driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();

  driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("User1");

  driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("Surname1");

  driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("123456789");

  driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");

  driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys("Test Address");

  driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("Test City");

  Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));

  select.selectByVisibleText("ANGOLA");

  driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");

  driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("user1");

  driver.findElement(By.name("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("user1");

  driver.findElement(By.name("register")).click();

  driver.close();

  driver.quit();

  }

}
```

Selenium RC version is 2.42.2 and firefox version 23.0

Error:

> FAILED: testRegister org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to
>   bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms Build info: version:
>   '2.19.0', revision: '15849', time: '2012-02-08 16:12:19' System info:
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_25' Driver info: driver.version: Driver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:95)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:157)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:93)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:136)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:78)
>     at com.test.webdriver.Driver.testRegister(Driver.java:23)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Please suggest me some solution. I killed Firefox session from Test Manager also, No luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, check what process is using the 7054 port with "netstat -anb" in cmd.

Secondly, you can change the WebDriver port for Firefox by using a custom profile :

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.PORT_PREFERENCE, 9876);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: I have checked netstat command but the port is free. Also tried the second solution but getting the same error in the console.

Comment: @user3843636 Something similar has been posted on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/i5NjiNkRJaY/T2jqmd51O0gJ)